# How to send multiple inputs from form to email via php script

Tags: php, forms

So I have this little php script which upon form completion sends the information to my email. I was able to make it work with one input, however, when trying to specify 3 different inputs, it won't go through.

I suspect that maybe I'm not specifying the inputs as I should with isset at the beginning of the if statement. I'm very new to php and appreciate all the help I can get, anyway here's the code.

```
       <?php

    if (isset($_POST['name' && 'emailq' && 'message'])){
  $visitor_name = $_POST['name'];
  $visitor_email = $_POST['emailq'];
  $visitor_message = $_POST['message'];

  $email_from = "LightDesigns";
  $email_subject = "new quot";
  $email_body = "Name: " .$visitor_name."\nEmail: " .$visitor_email."\n\n" 
 .$visitor_message;

  $to = "stefanvujic576@gmail.com";
  $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
  $result = mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
}
?>

<?php
$link_address = 'www.light-designsonline.co.uk';
if ($result){
    echo '<link href="css/phpcss.css" rel="stylesheet">';
    echo "<header></header>";
    echo '<h1>Thank You!</h1>';
    echo "<p>I'll get in contact with you shortly.</p>";

 }else{
    echo '<link href="css/phpcss.css" rel="stylesheet">';
    echo "<header></header>";
  ?>
  }
 <?php
  }
?>

<form action="quotform.php" method="POST" class="quote" name="quot">
        <div>
        <h1>Get a quot</h1>
        <hr align="left" style="width: 82%;">
            <label>Name</label><br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form" autocomplete required name="name">
                </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Email</label><br>
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" class="form" autocomplete required name="emailq"> 
                    </div>
                <div>
            <label>Message</label><br>
            <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message"></textarea>
        </div>
            <button class="button_1" type="submit" class="form"><span>Send</span></button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's wrong

```
if (isset($_POST['name' && 'emailq' && 'message'])){
```

it means to AND together 'name', 'emailq' and 'message' values, which will be a logical TRUE and checked if the $_POST array has a value with the key TRUE

what you need is

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['emailq']) && isset($_POST['message'])){
```

or you could use

```
if (isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['emailq'],$_POST['message'])){
```

as mentioned by Magnus Eriksson

each has to be a separate logical expression which are then ANDed together

Comment: Since their input does not cause an error, do you know what php was trying to do with that original syntax?

Comment: Yes, while this is true that `isset` syntax was wrong, how would that prevent him from passing the extra `$_POST` elements and creating the variables? PHP should've at least spat out an error in this case?

Comment: it and'd the 'name', 'emailq' and 'message' values, which will be a logical TRUE and checked if the $_POST array has a value with the key true

Comment: Just want to thank you guys for your answers, works very well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check inputs separately like in the code below.

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['emailq']) && isset($_POST['message']))
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check for those fields this way:

```
if (   isset($_POST['name'])
    && isset($_POST['emailq'])
    && isset($_POST['message'])) {
    //...
}
```

OR even use an array: Name you input fields like this: `name="input[name]"` and `name="input[mail]"` and so on. Then you can access the `input` array via `$_POST['input']`, which is much cleaner.